# Parsing json key:value in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a exchange rate API output like such:

[image]

I would like get an array to pass through another pipeline as a parameter to iterate over. However I have been fruitless in my endeavors. I would like to have an array of the currencies. In ADF terms I want to set my array variable to the properties of @activity('API Call').output.rates .

I have tried setting @activity('API Call').output.rates to both an array and a string variable (adding string() and array() to the content with out any luck. However, I have been able to set the string variable to @activity('API Call').output.rates.AED/AFN etc, however that is not what I needed. Those curly brackets around rates have got me a little stumped, if they were square brackets no problemo. I've also tried a few goes with string functions to no avail.

Can anyone with familiarity of Azure Dynamic Content push me in the right direction?

Comment: The curly brackets define rates as an object, not an array, so it appears you are trying to convert a JSON Object to an array. Can you provide a sample of the format you are after? Do you want an array of objects or just the decimal values? Are the rates property names (AED/AFN/etc) always the same?

Comment: I'd like to be able to iterate over the rate identifiers, so simply [AED, ADN, AFN, ...]. I would like to be able to do this so I can iterate over the array in case the properties do change (plus I don't want to hardcode 168 values as variable anyway).

Comment: Could you post and update your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around this solution by querying a reference table with the keys and iterating over the object. Obviously not the lightest and cleanest solution but it did fit better into my process than utilizing a function or anything like that.

The concession I had to make was that the keys were going to have to be known before hand, but given that new currencies do not pop up often (with the exception of cryptos, which I'm not working with).

Answer (score -3):

Rates is an object...  to get an array of the properties inside... you should use javascript's Object.keys() function

```
var keyArray = Object.keys(@activity('API Call').output.rates);

for(var index = 0; index < keyArray.length; index++){
    var message = 'Value of ' + keyArray[index];
    message += ' is: ' + @activity('API Call').output.rates[keyArray[index]];
    console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can use Javascript functions in Azure Data Factory.

Comment: You could call an Azure Function to do the conversion, and have it return the array.

Comment: may be a bit of an overkill to set up... but agreed...  an azure function running javascript (or any other supported language is probably needed here as the azure pipeline for-each requires an array...   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node

Comment: Coincidentally, I am being forced to retire an azure function and replace it with ADF, so that is a no go for me!